# Method in Script is never called

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a Projectile Script attached to a GameObject. Now i want to access the LinearProjectile() method in Projectile Script from Script A attached to GameObject A. Here i made a public field of type Projectile in Script A and passed in one GameObject where Projectile Script is attached.

To access LinearProjectile() method i just did.

```
projectile.LinearProjectile(transform.position, transform.rotation, this.direction, this.shotPower);
//Here is my method defination..

public void LinearProjectile(Vector3 position, Quaternion rotation, Vector2 direction, float force)
{
    Debug.Log("called");
    this.direction = direction;
    this.force = force;
    this.projectileType = ProjectileType.Linear;
}
```

All the field value  assigned in this method are in default state since this method is never called. How can I access this method from other GameObject Script.
I tried GetComponent().method() but even though i can't acess what is the error here? i spent alot of time to find out but no success.. Help me out

Comment: Where is `LinearProjectile()` located? In `Projectile` script? If that's so, where do you want to access `LinearProjectile()` ?

Comment: It's a method of Projectile Script and i want to access from Script A.

Answer (score 2):

Provided a scenario like this:

- We have a `GameObject` in scene, let's call it `Item`
- We have `ProjectileScript` attached to `Item`
- We have a `A` script attached to `Item`

All we need to do is to call inside `A` script:

```
gameObject.GetComponent<ProjectileScript>().LinearProjectile();
```

If it's on another `GameObject`, I would personally create field in script `A` to be used in `Inspector`, for example: `public GameObject ProjectileScriptHolder` and then just drag `GameObject` from scene that holds `ProjectileScript` into that variable in `Inspector` and the access it that way:

```
ProjectileScriptHolder.GetComponent<ProjectileScript>().LinearProjectile();
```

I would also check every `GetComponent<T>` before calling method as it might return null, ie:

```
ProjectileScript script = ProjectileScriptHolder.GetComponent<ProjectileScript>();
if (script != null)
    script.LinearProjectile();
```

If you can't attach item through `Inspector`, you can use `FindWithTag()` and find `GameObject` in scene provided it has proper `Tag` attached. `FindWithTag()` takes `string` as parameter and will look for `GameObject` with such tag in scene.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to access a script from another script on another gameobject!

**Way 1**

There is a simple way to do that, caching the script. (Assuming the name of the script is: "ProjectileScript")

On ScriptA you create a

```
public ProjectileScript pS;
```

and you need to initialise it, there is two ways:
1- on the inspector of GameObjectA, drag the GameObject with the projectileScript.

or

2.1- if the script is in the same game object:

```
pS = GetComponent<ProjectileScript> ();
```

2.2- if it is on another gameobject you might need to find this object somehow. Consider using a tag

```
 pS = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("projectile").GetComponent<"ProjectileScript">();
```

And cast it inside Script A:

```
pS.LinearProjectile();
```

**Way 2**

Or you can make a generic tag on the GameObject with the ProjectileScript and find it that way:

```
GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("projectile").GetComponent<"ProjectileScript">.LinearProjectile();
```

This make sense for you? Sorry my english.

Comment: Nope. I still can't access. Here in pS of type projectileScript unity wil throw you instance of projectileScript attached to the GameObject not the GameObject. So you can directly call pS.LinearProjectile(). Correct me if i am wrong. But i don't know why i am not able to access the LinearProjectile() method..

Comment: Ooops. I forgot to initiate it. :O

Comment: I've updated the code. I made some mistakes with brackets. Sorry.